# Защита от нераспознаваемых символов Îôèñ êîìïàíèè

Tags: java, xml, строки

Можно ли как то на java предусмотреть защиту от таких вот символов?

Îôèñ êîìïàíèè

иногда клиент отправляет xml где такие символы попадаются. 
и это ломает хранимые процедуры.

Comment: Это корректные юникодные символы; если что-то в хранимых процедурах ломается, нужно чинить эти самые хранимые процедуры

Comment: Это символы,записанные в кодировке windows-1251, которые отображаются в кодировке iso-8859-9. Смотрите, где вы накосячили с детектом кодировок. Читаете ли вы пролог XML где указана кодировка файла?

Comment: @andreymal, но не факт, что у него БД в юникоде))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изменить их вот так

```
String s = "text1 îìïàíèè text2";
System.out.println(StringUtils.stripAccents(s));

Output: text1 iiiaiee text2
```